# grid 12 column cant colour full column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

when not centered I can get full background color, when I'm centered it shrinks. I'm sorry my english so bad, please help me, I want a full background and center item for my navigation bar,

```css
.header__nav {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 50px);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.header__nav :is(div, ul) {
  background: red;
}

.header__menu {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.header__search {
  grid-column: 3/7;
}

.header__menu-nav {
  grid-column: 7/12;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="header__nav grid">
      <div class="header__menu">a
        <i class="fa-solid fa-xmarks-lines" style="color: #feffff"></i>
        <a href="#">menu</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header__search">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass" style="color: #feffff"></i>
        <a href="#">search</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="header__menu-nav">
        <div>
          <a href="#">components</a>
          <a href="#">case study</a>
          <a href="#">workflow</a>
          <a href="#">management center</a>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem requires some modifications in your html and css.

First of all, we can change the ul to div which contains the
components
case study
workflow
management center
links.

Because, ul has some styles of its own, and what you wanted to achieve can be done using the `display:flex` property of CSS.

Following is the complete code with the output:

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <header>
      <nav class="header__nav grid">
        <div class="header__menu navOption">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-xmarks-lines" style="color: #feffff"></i>
          <a href="#">menu</a>
        </div>
        <div class="header__search navOption">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass" style="color: #feffff"></i>
          <a href="#">search</a>
        </div>
        <div class="header__menu-nav">
          <a href="#">components</a>
          <a href="#">case study</a>
          <a href="#">workflow</a>
          <a href="#">management center</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
.header__nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 50px);
}

.navOption {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__nav :is(div) {
  background: red;
}

.header__menu {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.header__search {
  grid-column: 3/7;
}

.header__menu-nav {
  grid-column: 7/12;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
}
```

Output:
[image: Final output]